# Org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: whats wrong?

Tags: java, spring

I get this error for this test ,what is wrong with my code? what can I do to understand the problem

```
 @InjectMocks
        BookController controller;

        @Mock
        BookService bookService;  // will be inject to BookController

        MockMvc mockMvc;

        @Mock
        View mockView;

        @Before
        public void setUp() throws Exception {
            new BookController(bookService);
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
            mockMvc = standaloneSetup(controller)
                    .setSingleView(mockView)
                    .build();
        }


        @Test
        public void showBookListPage() throws Exception {
            securityService.autologin("admin","admin");
            List<Book> expectedBookList =  new  ArrayList <Book>();
            BookService bookService = mock(BookService.class);
            when(bookService.findAll()).thenReturn(expectedBookList);

             mockMvc.perform(get(" /book/bookList"))
                    .andExpect(view().name("bookList"))
                    .andExpect(model().attributeExists("bookList"))
                    .andExpect(model().attribute("bookList", hasItems(expectedBookList.toArray())));
        }
```

Full error explanation of error, what suggestion do you have ?

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
```

Everything seems right but I get this error always

Comment: It is because you call `mock(BookService)` and you also have the annotation I guess; the instance injected into the controller will not be the one you call `when()` on.